# How does one create a realistic language for their world?

Tags: language

Within your world, would you want to create a simplistic language for one society while having English or native "Earth" language be the other?

When creating a language, how would you go about naming the "Language"? I feel naming it may be key to creating it? I want the people within the world to have more foreign less realistic language. Would this be bad thing or would it be intriguing?

Comment: Thank you! I am new to this so I am learning! I am still trying to figure out a base to build on. I just recently decided to start a world and I think figuring out the people is a big part of "building" the world as a whole. I will definitely make sure to look into other posts before posting to prevent duplicates. I appreciate your input! :)

Comment: I would highly recommend you read into [Tolkein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Languages_constructed_by_J._R._R._Tolkien) and his creation of languages as an excellent example.  I think creating a simple cypher and then converting the letters of the alphabet to different symbols would be a fairly straightforward and realistic attempt.

Comment: I will look into this! :)

Comment: Last time I checked, there was a proposal for a Constructed Languages SE. If it ever gets off the ground, that might be a good resource for you as well.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Once you have 5 reputation (which you should have now; duplicates mean more ways for people searching to find what they want, so I gave you an upvote) you can also access our [Meta Site](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/) if you have questions about using the site. Once you are at 20 rep feel free to join the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor). Have fun!

Comment: Thank you all so much! Such great info and I appreciate the support. :)

Comment: if you have a look at [this guide](http://rollforfantasy.com/guides/language-creation.php) it might help